# Transport Filters in Delphi XE Datasnap

Tags: delphi, filter, delphi-xe, datasnap, transport

When I try to create a custom Transport Filter for datasnap and use it, when I run the client app i get an error stating:

Exception TDBXError in Module ProjectAdminClient.exe. Filter Log Rejected setup parameter FilterUnit given value 1024. At this point the server communication is not possible due to this incompatibility.

What is causing this?

Answer (score 3):

Are you using Filter parameters? I've also created custom transport filters, but never encountered this error. Here's an example do-nothing log filter...

```
unit LogFilter;
interface
uses
  SysUtils, DBXPlatform, DBXTransport;

type
  TLogFilter = class(TTransportFilter)
  public
    constructor Create; override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function ProcessInput(const Data: TBytes): TBytes; override;
    function ProcessOutput(const Data: TBytes): TBytes; override;
    function Id: UnicodeString; override;
  end;

const
  LogFilterName = 'Log';

implementation
uses
  CodeSiteLogging;

constructor TLogFilter.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  CodeSite.Send(csmBlue,'TLogFilter.Create');
end;

destructor TLogFilter.Destroy;
begin
  CodeSite.Send(csmBlue,'TLogFilter.Destroy');
  inherited Destroy;
end;

function TLogFilter.ProcessInput(const Data: TBytes): TBytes;
begin
  Result := Data;
  CodeSite.Send(csmYellow, 'ProcessInput ' + IntToStr(Length(Data)),
    TEncoding.ASCII.GetString(Data));
end;

function TLogFilter.ProcessOutput(const Data: TBytes): TBytes;
begin
  Result := Data;
  CodeSite.Send(csmOrange, 'ProcessOutput ' + IntToStr(Length(Data)),
    TEncoding.ASCII.GetString(Data));
end;

function TLogFilter.Id: UnicodeString;
begin
  Result := LogFilterName;
end;

initialization
  TTransportFilterFactory.RegisterFilter(LogFilterName, TLogFilter);
finalization
  TTransportFilterFactory.UnregisterFilter(LogFilterName);
end.
```

This one works just fine for me (one of the example from my upcoming Delphi XE DataSnap Development Essentials courseware manual).

Groetjes, Bob Swart

Comment: Where did you place / add or attach the code? I don't see it. Feel free to e-mail it to me.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question when I had a similar problem using Dr Bob's LogFilter from his Delphi 2010 Datasnap Whitepaper.

The problem, at least partially, is that I had the ZLibCompression filter loaded at the same time I was trying to work with the log filter. The clue was in the ServerContainerUnit1.dfm

```
Filters = <
  item
    FilterId = 'ZLibCompression'
    Properties.Strings = (
      'CompressMoreThan=1024')
  end>
```

I saw the 1024 which was also in the error and figured it was worth trying without the ZLib filter. I removed it from the client and server. Now the log filter works. I get the server time and get breakpoints to work in the LogFilter code.